# How to "write" with the strings of an array a text?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, key, matching

So my question might not be the best, so sorry for that.
I have an array with strings and want to write a text with the help of another array using it as the order/key. This is the Input:

```
$words =["I","am","cool"];
$order =["2","0","1","0","1","2"];
//var_export($words);
// array (
//     0 => 'I',
//     1 => 'am',
//     2 => 'cool',
// )
```

I want to use *$order* as some sort of key to rearrange *$words* so I can get this Output:

```
"Cool I am I am cool"
```

Help is much appreciated, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the values of `$order` as the keys for `$words`.

```
$words =["I","am","cool"];
$order =["2","0","1","0","1","2"];
$output = '';
foreach($order as $key) {
   $output .= $words[$key] . ' ';
}
echo ucfirst(trim($output));
```

Demo: https://eval.in/780785

The `empty($real_key)` is to check if it is the first iteration. Also could be `== 0`.

Comment: One question. When I run the code, I get an error which says that every number from my $order is undefined (index undefined:   1). My $order is created with $order = explode("\n", $string);  Every number is one paragraph in the string. Why doesn't it work? Thank you anyways for your solution :)

Comment: This is not the best answer. This code will error when you accidentally use a value that is not in the index range of `$words`

Comment: @RST An `if(empty` could easily enough be added. It is unclear what the expected result would be though, as I read it the pairing was related.

Comment: That is my point, yet another check to perform. Putting strings together is better done by using an array and then implode. Much cleaner.

Comment: @RST That's an opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the use of `array_map` and `join`

There is no need for

- side-effecting manual iteration using `foreach`
- `if` statements or ternary (`?:`) expressions
- variable reassignment
- string concatenation using `.`
- checking array lengths

Here we go

```
function map_indexes_to_words ($indexes, $words) {
  $lookup = function ($i) use ($words) {
    return $words[(int) $i];
  };
  return join(' ', array_map($lookup, $indexes));
}

$words = ["I","am","cool"];
$order = ["2","0","1","0","1","2"];

echo map_indexes_to_words($order, $words);
// 'cool I am I am cool'
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with an empty array.
Then loop through the order array and add the word array part to the new string.

```
$my_string= array();

    foreach ( $order as $index ) {
        $index = int($index);
        $my_string[] = ( isset($words[ $index]) ) ? $words[ $index ] : '' ); 
    }

$my_string = implode(' ', $my_string);
echo my_string;
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over order and use it's values as keys to words; Convert the following code to php it should be pretty simple...

```
  foreach (string orderIndexString in order) {
    int orderIndexInt = System.Convert.ToInt16(orderIndexString); // convert string to int
    if(orderIndexInt < 0 || orderIndexInt >= words.Length)
      continue;

    print (words[orderIndexInt]);  // either print or add it to another string
  }
```